# Multiple matrix elements across different rows and columns

Tags: r, matrix, subset, apply

I am attempting to extract specific row elements across columns in a matrix or dataframe in R. A simplified example is:

```
dat<-rbind(rnorm(10, 0, 1), rnorm(10, 0, 1))

rown<-c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2)
```

where I wish to return the row index specified by rown across columns of dat. I can do this with a loop:

```
for(i in 1:spec.num){print(dat[,i][rown[i]])}
```

but I know there must be a way to do this with apply or something similar. However, I cannot figure out how to incorporate the elements of rown into the apply function. I could also easily do this with mapply if dat were a list of columns, but that is not ideal either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `cbind` to create row/column index matrix and use it to subset values.

```
dat[cbind(rown, seq_len(ncol(dat)))]
#Equivalent call and maybe easy to understand
#dat[cbind(rown, 1:ncol(dat))]
#[1] -0.560 -0.230  1.559  0.111 -0.556  1.715  0.461 -1.265 -0.687 -0.473
```

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
dat<-rbind(rnorm(10, 0, 1), rnorm(10, 0, 1))
```